# Copying list of files from one folder to other in R

Tags: r, copy-paste, directory

I am trying to bulk move files of different kinds in R.

```
origindir <- c("c:/origindir")
targetdir <- c("c/targetdir")
filestocopy <- c("myfile.doc", "myfile.rda", "myfile.xls", 
                 "myfile.txt", "myfile.pdf", "myfile.R")
```

I tried the following, but do not know how to do for all files:

```
file.copy(paste (origindir, "myfile.doc", sep = "/"), 
          paste (targetdir, "myfile.doc", sep = "/"), 
          overwrite = recursive, recursive = FALSE, 
          copy.mode = TRUE)
```

I do not know how to do this.

Comment: use `lapply` to iterate over your vector of `filestocopy`, create an anonymous function in your lapply call to replace everywhere you have `myfile.doc`...something like `lapply(filestocopy, function(x) file.copy(paste(origindir, x, sep = "/"), ...`

Comment: Also, look at `file.path()` as a replacement for `paste` above, it is supposed to be "faster than paste" and is used extensively within R itself.

Comment: @Chase I think the from and to arguments in `file.copy` are actually vectorized.

Comment: @joran - cool! If that's the case, it should be as simple as replacing the `myfile.doc` with `filestocopy` then...right?

Comment: @Chase Yup. Just tried it out-from can be a vector of file paths and to can be a single directory path or vector of file paths.

Comment: I didn't know it was vectorized.  I've been using it inefficiently for some time now.  Thanks Joran.

Comment: When Chase's example with `lapply()` I get a list with `TRUE` statements in the console. Is it suppressable?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Joran and Chase have already pointed out in the comments, all you need to do is:

```
file.copy(from=filestocopy, to=targetdir, 
          overwrite = recursive, recursive = FALSE, 
          copy.mode = TRUE)
```

Then, if you're actually *moving* the files, remove the originals with:

```
file.remove(filestocopy)
```

Comment: I got this message: `Error in file.copy(from = filestocopy, to = targetdir, overwrite = recursive,  :  object 'recursive' not found`. Isn't recursive a build in function?

Comment: I had the same error. But the following code worked for me:

`flist <- list.files(filestocopy, ".csv", full.names = TRUE);
file.copy(flist, targetdir)`

Comment: You want `overwrite = TRUE` instead of `overwrite = recursive`. That'll solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding Chase's suggestion.

```
lapply(filestocopy, function(x) file.copy(paste (origindir, x , sep = "/"),  
          paste (targetdir,x, sep = "/"), recursive = FALSE,  copy.mode = TRUE))
```

Comment: I don't know why you would use this when the default `file.copy` is able to handle a vector of file names.

Comment: NO. For some unknown reason. `Error in file.copy(from = TBL$FROM, to = TBL$TO[1]) : 
  more 'from' files than 'to' files`' `TBL` is a tibble