# How to get the particular files from a directory in R?

Tags: r

I have a directory `A` with `67000` txt files and a data frame with a column having `400` file names.

I need to make a directory `B` with these `400` files chosen from `A`.

How can I do this in R ?

Comment: Try `lapply(yourdf$yourcolumn, function(x) read.table(text=as.character(x), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`  If the column is `character` class, you don't need to wrap with `as.character`.  After reading the files, you can `write` the files in the new directory with `write.csv`.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299712/copying-list-of-files-from-one-folder-to-other-in-r) may be more straightforward

Comment: In the second solution, original directory is specified.

Comment: exactly ... reading/writing is super time wasting, second approach is more intuitive.

Comment: @akrun please consider writing up an answer ans not to leave the question unanswered

Comment: @iraserd If the OP was able to get it right from the link, we can close it as duplicate.