# Subsetting Images out of a Folder

Tags: r

We have a folder with 4000 images. We would like to subset out a set of images into a new folder. We have a text file with a list of all of the images we would like to subset out. Is there an easy way to do this in windows or R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a `images.txt` file with the filenames of the images you want to subset (each on a new line), then you can import the list with

```
images <- readLines("images.txt")
```

and make a new director and copy your subset with

```
dir.create("subset")
for (i in seq_along(images)) {
  file.copy(images[i], paste0("subset/", images[i]))
}
```

assuming your working directory is the folder with the images, e.g. with `setwd()` or using the `here` package.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (not tested) with `n` the sample size:

```
n=100
newdir <- "C:\\Documents\\R\\wd\\text"
myfiles <- list.files()
mysample <- sample(myfiles,n)
file.copy(mysample,newdir)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10301068/9670603) on moving files